# How closely can string theory mimic asymptotic safety for gravity?

Tags: string-theory, renormalization, quantum-gravity

Asymptotic safety in quantum gravity has various problems, but (as I see it) it has two points in its favor.

First, the hypothesis has apparently [passed a significant test](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/240515/how-do-people-go-about-looking-for-asymptotic-safety-in-quantum-gravity) which skeptics predicted it would fail (see the 2016 paper cited by Arnold Neumaier).

Second, it was [successfully employed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/41199/was-the-higgs-mass-correctly-predicted-by-asymptotic-safety-of-gravity) to predict the mass of the Higgs boson. As Daniel de França ("MTd2") has remarked, that might be the first confirmed prediction of a quantum gravitational theory!

So I am wondering whether string theory can mimic asymptotic safety. For example, could there be a stringy regime in which gravity is described by one of the truncations of Einstein gravity that has been shown to be asymptotically safe?

Answer (score 3):

> So I am wondering whether string theory can mimic asymptotic safety.

it's worth noting that all developments in string theory converge to the observation that fundamentally gravity is not a local field theory, while the claim of asymptotic safity is just the contrary, that it is a local field theory at arbitrary high energy.

Within perturbative string theory itself, gravity is carried by the closed string sector, which fundamentally is not a local field theory, but a string field theory, non-local at about the string scale.

Within non-perturbative string theory, gravity is argued to be holographically dual to a local and conformal field theory (AdS/CFT), and as such is not itself a local field theory.

But also apart from the a priori assumption that quanta of gravity a carried by strings, people see the scaling behaviour of Bekenstein-Hawking entropy and conclude that if this entropy is to be carried by quantum degrees of freedom, then this cannot be those of of a local field theory. The AdS/CFT correspondence is in a way a grand generalization of this phenomenon.

A quick, clean, informative  and concise account of this is here:

- Assaf Shomer, "A pedagogical explanation for the non-renormalizability of gravity" ([arXiv:0709.3555](https://arxiv.org/abs/0709.3555))

see in particular the last little section IV.

You might also enjoy googling for *"Jacques Distler" "Asymptotic safety"* to see what one particular string theorist has to say in detail about the AS claims.

Comment: Thanks for the well-constructed, intuitive overview. (off-topic: the "for more see" link on your profile doesn't seem to work)

Comment: @JohnForkosh thanks for the alert. I have fixed the link. Regarding AS, I also made a note on the nLab here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/asymptotic+safety

Answer (score 0):

There is now a paper exploring [the possibility of an asymptotically safe regime just below the field-theory limit of string theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.07894). As a basic test of plausibility, they check for compatibility with the weak gravity conjecture. Whether the higher-derivative gravitational terms descended from string theory are compatible with asymptotic safety, should also be a key issue to investigate.